# MyBB how to display most recent threads at top of index, pulled from a specific important category?

Tags: posts, mybb

I have a plugin on the side of my forum that shows ALL the most recent posts in a side bar, but I want to have a section at the top of my index that shows the most recent posts ONLY from a specific category.

For example, the category I'm talking about has 3 forums inside of it that are very important and I want to feature new posts in those forums much more prominently than any other category on my forum.  I would like to do this WITHOUT the need for anything RSS related.

If you can supply me with a basic template of coding where I can fill in the category ID or fill in the individual forum IDs that I want new threads pulled from, that would be fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: No one has has answered this because either they don't know `mybb` or they don't like the "give me code" feel.

Answer (score 0):

Possible options are:

- Check the plugin options to see if can do it already.
- Check to see if there are other plugins that do it.
- Write your own plugin using this pseudo-SQL to get the data

```sql
   select top 10 *
   from posts 
   inner join forum on posts.forumID = forum.forumID
   inner join @categories on forum.categoryID = @category.CategoryID
   order by posts.dateCreated desc
```